# How Do I Traverse The DOM with Cypress Conditionally?

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I would like to click the "View profile" button when the `firstName` of the user is equal to "Luke". There will be many users on one page.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a datcy="viewProfileButton">View profile</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h5 datacy="firstName">Luke</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Cypress Test:**

`cy.get('[datacy="firstName"]').contains($firstName)...`

I've got to this point, but I am struggling with `.parents()` and other Cypress traversing options to move up the `div`, and then back down.

Comment: Is there a `Descendant["firstName"]` or some similar option you can use with your `.contains` condition?

Comment: A `Descendant` would allow you to reach down into the `div` tree to look for your first name, without having to walk back up the tree.

Comment: I could put this `[datacy="${firstName}"]` at the highest `div` and then look for it with `$firstName` after I wrap the `firstName`.

Comment: In react I just did this `<Box datacy={firstName + "UserCard"}`. I guess this will be a viable solution. However, it'd be good to know how to go up and then down the DOM tree.

Comment: This is what I mean: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.parent()` and `.children()` function are pretty static and can be prone to cause flakiness if the structure of the HTML changes.

I would suggest setting up your HTML to allow for downward traversal from a higher level element.

In your case, if you have a common `datacy` attribute on the upper most `<div>` you can use `cy.contains()` and `find()` to do all the heavy lifting for you.

```html
<!-- Added a second profile for example -->
<div datacy="profile">
    <div>
        <a datacy="viewProfileButton">View Luke's profile</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h5 datacy="firstName">Luke</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div datacy="profile">
    <div>
        <a datacy="viewProfileButton">View Alice's profile</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h5 datacy="firstName">Alice</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
// cy.contains returns the <div datacy='profile'> containing a child with the text 'Luke'
it('get link', () => {
  cy.contains('[datacy="profile"]', 'Luke') 
    .find('a')
    .should('have.text', "View Luke's profile");

  cy.contains('[datacy="profile"]', 'Alice') 
    .find('a')
    .should('have.text', "View Alice's profile");
});
```

[Using `cy.contains()` to get parent element when child element contains text](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Specify-a-selector-to-return-a-specific-element)

Comment: A great solution, thank you for spending the time writing your answer!